# Sammy.js exceptions stack trace

Tags: sammy.js

It seems that Sammy.js catches the exceptions that happen within the .get callbacks, and it prints something like

```
[Fri Feb 01 2013 14:12:46 GMT+0000 (GMT)] body 500 Error get *error message* Error {}
```

so is there a way to get the full stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, raise_errors can be set to re-throw the errors, for example

```
app = Sammy(...);
app.raise_errors = true;
app.run();
```